# In legacy application: Implementing new module using struts as controller

Tags: struts2, struts1

As of now my Java EE application controller is build using Http Serlvets for 8 modules
And there is a new module to be added, can I build this new module container using struts1?

What I believe is, this is possible, as these modules are using the front controller pattern for each module.
And as I add new module, I can configure it using my struts1 front controller ActionServlet.
Am I thinking correctly?

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>module1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xyz.module1.BasicsServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>module1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>Module1.xp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>Module9.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

PS: I believe if the above is possible,then we can use strut2 **also**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. below is my web.xml,In My code `MyServlet` is extending `ActionServlet` and `ImageFormationServlet` is extending `HttpServlet`.

```
<web-app>    
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.core.system.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageFormationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.core.system.servlet.ImageFormationServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ImageFormationServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/servlet/ImageFormationServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```